# Flash Player not present in Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome

So I recently upgraded to 12.04 (even though I hate Unity), and after the installation froze and my computer would no longer boot, after booting from a USB stick and installing 12.04 fresh, I downloaded Chrome. However, Flash Player (which is supposed to be built in) is not present.

Whenever I try to watch a video, I get a notification to install flash player, and the most help that Adobe's website gives is this technote
However, when I go to , there is no result for Flash except for this entry under the table for MIME types for the vlc plugin:
video/flv Flash video .flv

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate where you "downloaded" Chrome from. I suspect you downloaded Chromium, which doesn't come with an "integrated" Flash Player. Also, type `about:` in the "Chrome" browser's address bar and hit `enter`. Post that information in your question.

Comment: Install restricted extras using Synaptic. It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome for 64 bit does not come with Flash (see [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108381)).  Chrome (64 bit) will try and use the Flash it finds on your system, but if you don't have it, then you need to [install it](https://askubuntu.com/a/99222/43660).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ubuntu Software Center, search for Adobe Flash plugin.  The plugin works for Firefox, Chromium, SeaMonkey, etc...

Comment: the plugin works for firefox but didn't work for chrome 37 for me. I am on Ubuntu 14